# How to Send bulk mails using javax.mail API efficiently? & Can we use reuse authenticated sessions to improve speed?

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am able to send a mail using javax.mail API. But the problem here is on an average for each mail it taking around 4.3 seconds to send to destination.

If I am sending a 20 mails sequentially, it takes around 86.599 seconds. For my requirement this approach will not work. I am looking for an approach which can send large number of mails in less time.

When I looked at the debug log, the API is trying to authenticate to SMTP server for each and every message it sending. But I am creating a session only one time and using the same session for all the mails I am sending. Now my question is Isn't it a overhead process every time authenticating itself to the smtp server.  Isn't there a better approach ?

Below is the log trace you may find helpful.

```
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
```

Please let me know your thoughts on this and any help on this is really appreciated.

-Narendra

Comment: send bulk email by exploitating sendmail.

Comment: sorry I can't share my code here and I can't use sendmail .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How are you sending the messages?  The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq-135477.html#send) suggests that the static `Transport.send` method will open a fresh connection for each message, as it is a convenience method that creates a suitable `Transport` instance, connects it, calls `sendMessage` and then closes the connection again.  If you get your own `Transport` instance from the `Session` you can connect once, then call `sendMessage` repeatedly to send several messages on the one connection, and finally `close` it.  Something along the lines of (untested):

```
Transport t = session.getTransport();
t.connect();
try {
  for(Message m : messages) {
    m.saveChanges();
    t.sendMessage(m, m.getAllRecipients());
  }
} finally {
  t.close();
}
```

Updated to use try with resources block:

```
try (Transport t = session.getTransport()) {
    t.connect();
    for(Message m : messages) {
        m.saveChanges();
        t.sendMessage(m, m.getAllRecipients());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Curently I am using Transport.send(). I will test my code with session.getTransport().sendMessage(message,
        addressarray);

Comment: @Narendra it's not quite as simple as that, but I've edited my answer with a more detailed example.

Comment: Thanks for your code snippet. I tried my code with sendMessage method and now the time for sending mails is reduced to half the time when compared to using send(). However I have one question here that is: what is the use of savechanges()? Calling savechanges is expensive right? and in what cased we should call this? Please let me know.

Comment: @Narendra I just put it in to show the minimal change from the static `send` method if you want to batch several messages over one connection.  The static `send` calls `saveChanges` on the message before sending it, you may be able to avoid that in your case if you know your message headers are already up to date.

Comment: @Ian Roberts , i am just clarifying,  in your answer does it mean that multiple email addresses are associated with multiple Message objects?
And inside  for loop, each Message obj's recipient address is taken individually each time?
Please suggest

Comment: @NishiBangar I'm not entirely sure what you are asking - each message has its own list of recipients, and the message will be sent to those addresses.

Comment: @Ian Roberts, Are you mentioning looping messages like.. Message m 1 [subject 1, body1, recipient1, recipient2, recipient3... ], Message m 2 [subject 2, body2, recipient1, recipient2, recipient3... ], Message m 3 [subject 3, body3, recipient1, recipient2, recipient3... ] etc ?

Answer (score 10):

I got the same requirement at work. I must send bulk emails and standalone email. I do not find simple and satisfactory answer: bulk emails can be sent using a single connection but standalone email cannot until I create an asynchronous buffering to send emails in batch.

Last but not least, using a lot of `Transport` connection in a short time can lead to a `no more socket handles are available` because all ports are stuck in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

I finally conclude the best will be an SMTP connection pool and because no library exists (at least free) [I create mine](https://github.com/nithril/smtp-connection-pool) using Apache Common Pool and Java Mail:

```
//Declare the factory and the connection pool, usually at the application startup
SmtpConnectionPool smtpConnectionPool = new SmtpConnectionPool(SmtpConnectionFactoryBuilder.newSmtpBuilder().build());

//borrow an object in a try-with-resource statement or call `close` by yourself
try (ClosableSmtpConnection transport = smtpConnectionPool.borrowObject()) {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, false);
    mimeMessageHelper.addTo("to@example.com");
    mimeMessageHelper.setFrom("from@example.com");
    mimeMessageHelper.setSubject("Hi!");
    mimeMessageHelper.setText("Hello World!", false);
    transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
}

//Close the pool, usually when the application shutdown
smtpConnectionPool.close();
```

Comment: How long do the connections last? Suppose I have different sessions assigned for different 'from' organizational addresses (some are auth , some not, some different host)? Is it safe to assume that all are smtp? What about password, can it be made to use the session authenticator instead of requiring the username and password in the build stage?

Comment: The connection last the duration [you have configured](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/BaseGenericObjectPool.html#setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis%28long%29). About authentication, the [`SmtpConnectionFactoryBuilder#session`](https://github.com/nithril/smtp-connection-pool/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nlab/smtp/transport/SmtpConnectionFactoryBuilder.java#L37) can take an `Authenticator`. Different hosts will  require different connection pool. When you write different session, you mean Transport?

Comment: We have different SMTP hosts depending on the from address of the email. And different authentic too even for the same host depending on what  msexchange account is being used.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are either not relevant or too complex to implement. So here's I am posting the easiest solution to send bulk emails in Spring Boot

Just use

```
mimeMessageHelper.setBcc(emailList);
```

Where,

`mimeMessageHelper` is `MimeMessageHelper`, `emailList` is `String[] emailList`

**NOTE:**

Make sure that you are not using

```
mimeMessageHelper.setTo(emailList)
```

Otherwise, it will show all receivers' email address in the receiver's received email.

For more reference, [This](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-java-mail-tutorial) and [This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email) can help you to learn how to send emails in Spring Boot

Answer (score 0):

No idea if the standard Java mail API allows what you are trying to accomplish (session reuse), but you may consider using multi-threading:

I would use a ThreadPool and submit mail send jobs to it. Then you do any error handling / resending within the job class code, which is executed by the ThreadPool asynchronously, and your main thread can resume to do other things. Submitting a job will only take milliseconds. It been a while since I implemented something with thread pools in Java, but I remember it was fairly easy and straightforward. If you Google "Java ThreadPool" you find plenty of material.

Comment: Hi FelixD, Thanks for your answer. I am mainly looking for session reuse bcz authenticating every time is a overhead process. My main goal here is to reduce the time taken for sending mail from 4seconds to around 1 second. You suggested using theads, but it will not improve the time taken for sending mail from src system to destination.

Comment: Hi Narenda, no worries and thanks for your comment. I see your point - unfortunately I can't really help with more advanced use of the Java mail API, I have only done the simple sending with it. I hope my suggestion with multi-threading might be helpful for others though, as there are situations where this solves the issue (e.g. when mail sending is keeping your main app busy too long etc). Of course the load on the mail server on the other end also does not get less by my approach...

Comment: Thanks FelixD for your reply. As Ian Robert suggested in above answer, using sendMessage is useful for my scenario and it reducing time for mail delivery as it reusing the existing session object. But implementing it is a not an easy task as Ian Robert told.

Comment: You're right. I hadn't noticed Ian Robert's reply when I wrote the last comment. What he writes looks interesting, maybe I'll need that some time as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

I developed a way to send 1000 emails in less than 1 min. This email has only text. Heavy HTML takes approx 2 mins.

```
@Async("bulk-email")
void sendBulkEmail(List<EmailMessage> emailMessages){
     // EmailMessage is a custom object with properties like to, cc, subject.
     Collection<List<EmailMessage>> partitionedList = Lists.partition(emailMessages, 
         50); // Google Guava library.
     
     try{
        ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(10);
        customThreadPool.submit(()-> 
        partitionedList.parallelStream.forEach(this::sendEmails)).get();
     }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

This will create 10 threads with each thread will send 50 emails with one Session and one connection.

```
private void sendEmails(List<EmailMessage> messages){
   
   Session session = createSession();
   try (Transport t = session.getTransport()) {
       t.addTransportListener(transportListener);
       t.connect();
       for(Message m : messages) {
          MimeMessage mime = createMimeMessage(session, m);
          mime.saveChanges();
          t.sendMessage(mime, mime.getAllRecipients());
       }
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Thread pooling as it gives very good performance.I have implemented and sharing you the below code snippet.

```
try  {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool("no. of threads"); // no. of threads is depend on your cpu/memory usage it's better to test with diff. no. of threads.
    Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(message); // message is the javax.mail.Message
    executor.execute(worker);
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```